# Is it possible to write single query?

Tags: mysql

first table :question

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | createdBy | question | attachment | contributor | doctorId | ipAddress | userAgent | views |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 |         1 | hiii     | NULL       | NULL        |        3 | NULL      | NULL      |  NULL |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Second Table :view

```
+----+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
| id | ipAddress | userId | count | questionId |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
|  1 | NULL      |      1 |  NULL |          1 |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
```

I want the data question table id,createdBy,question , count ( how many user is viewed the question from view table where question=1);
how to write single query ;

Comment: This is the most unclear question I've seen today.

Comment: It's like an International Border or raw field. where is your que? :p  Improve formatting and Just asked what you wanna know?

Answer (score 1):

A simple COUNT(DISTINCT ...) should do it:-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId)
FROM view
WHERE question = 1
```

To get the other details on the question, do a join and add a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT question.id,
        question.createdBy,
        question.question,
        COUNT(DISTINCT userId)
FROM view
INNER JOIN question
WHERE view.question = 1
GROUP BY id,
        createdBy,
        question
```